# Automate match the following java string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, selenium

I have following data in array

I need to match the input value with Month.

month [Jan, Feb,March,April,May,June,July,August,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec] data in excel 
input value should match the month as below. data in excel or inside the code

This all value goes in different chart[test cases] which as some month in each.

how can I automate that input value should match month.

Chart 1 =[Jan,Feb,June,Oct,Nov]

Chart 2 = [March,April,Oct,Nov,Dec]

Chart 3 = [May, Aug,Sept]

Chart 4 = April,July,Aug,Sept,Oct,Now,Dec]

Jan = home|book|calendar|bag

Feb =  school

March = date

April = apple|banana

May = ice

June = water

July = bottle|glass

Aug = milk

Sept = bread|eggs|smoothie

Oct =  oats

Nov = watermelon

Dec = yogurt

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you please clarify?